# Nut size of earth stud on a can light

Tags: electrical, wire

This should be a simple to answer but I am not sure how to phrase it for google.

For a standard recessed light (aka can-light) in the US, what is the nut/thread size of the earth stud on the inside of the unit?  This is the stud that accepts the flying lead earth from the light fixture.

Comment: 10-32 generally green https://www.homedepot.com/p/202956750

Comment: @Tyson Those are grounding screws.  I am after the nut that tightens onto the threaded stud on the inside of the can-light

Comment: I don’t know what part you mean then.  That’s what my can lights use to attach the green or bare ground wire.

Comment: The can lights I have, have a threaded stud sticking out on the inside of the can that can be used the attaching an earth lead.  The LED replacement kits I have been using have  such a flying lead for eating teh electronics component

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK ..I Just found it by looking online at the instructions of the LED kits I have been buying.  The nut I was looking for is

> No. 8-32 Hex Nut